# Parameterized Angular CLI build call from Maven (Eirslett's plugin)

Tags: maven, angular-cli, maven-frontend-plugin

I'm building a Java web app that packages in a WAR static resources. These static resources are built through Angular-CLI.

The Maven build triggers the ng build through Eirslett's `maven-frontend-plugin`, with npm scripts and the npm mojo.

Problem is, I would like to use a custom `base href` depending on Maven build parameters, and I did not manage to pass it to ng, either by environment variables or parameters.

**Can someone tell me how to pass parameters to a ng build from Maven?**

Code:

**pom.xml**

```
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>node install</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>--registry=${npm.internal.registry} --userconfig ${basedir}/.jenkins-npmrc install</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm build</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>--userconfig ${basedir}/.jenkins-npmrc run-script build</arguments>
                                <environmentVariables>
                                    <test>this-does-not-work</test>
                                </environmentVariables>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm test</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>run-script test</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v8.6.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>5.3.0</npmVersion>
                        <installDirectory>.</installDirectory>
                        <nodeDownloadRoot>${node.internal.repo}</nodeDownloadRoot>
                        <npmDownloadRoot>${npm.internal.registry}/npm/-/</npmDownloadRoot>
                        <installDirectory>.</installDirectory>
                        <workingDirectory>.</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    (...)
    "build": "ng build --prod --env=prod --bh=process.env.test --base-href=process.env.test",
    (...)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm solving similar problem by having in (assumes regular *angular-cli* `build` entry in `package.json`):

### pom.xml

```
...
<execution>
  <id>build</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>npm</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <arguments>run build -- --base-href ${context.root}/</arguments>
  </configuration>
</execution>
...
```

You can then control `<context.root>` property via Maven profiles and having default value in parents Maven module `<properties>` section.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to pass the Maven project version to my NPM script and the below worked for me with the `exec-maven-plugin`:

pom.xml

```
<execution>
    <id>my-npm-build</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>compile</phase>
    <configuration>
        <executable>npm</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>run</argument>
            <argument>my-npm-script</argument>
        </arguments>
        <environmentVariables>
            <mvn_prj_vrsn>${project.version}</mvn_prj_vrsn>
        </environmentVariables>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

And in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "my-npm-script": "echo %mvn_prj_vrsn% &&[my other commands]
}
```

The above was for windows, in case of Linux use

```
$mvn_prj_vrsn
```

Comment: This also worked for me. I used this gist as a more complete reference: https://gist.github.com/phillipgreenii/7c954e3c3911e5c32bd0

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me : 
On my pom.xml : i make a call to my script **run build:prod**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>

        <configuration>
            <nodeVersion>v11.8.0</nodeVersion>
            <npmVersion>6.5.0</npmVersion>
            <workingDirectory>src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>install node and npm</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>npm install</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>npm run build</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build:prod</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

On my angular app ( packaga.json )  :

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer --base-href /myBaseUrl/"
},
```

You could personalize the script as you like.